# How to restore db from particular checkpoint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

Just like OS , Can I define checkpoint in DB ?
Here checkpoint means let suppose I have added 100 records. Now I want to define checkpoint. And after defining the checkpoint, I again add another 100 records.
After some time if I want to delete last added 100 records with respective to defined checkpoint.is it possible in mysql?

Comment: MySQL does not support this. You may backup your DB at needed checkpoint and restore it when needed. Also you may add autoutilized `created_at` and/or `updated_at` columns into your tables and take their values into account during data processing.

Comment: With MariaDB there is a [system versioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) that does a similar sort of thing, especially if the 100 records are a single transaction. There isn't exactly a revert but a few self joins on a `delete` can recreate another checkpoint based on what was there.